# Microsoft CRM - Solution manifest import failure, error 80048033 without any detail

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-365

I'm importing solution to Microsoft Dynamics 365 CRM, but it fails with this error from trace log:

```
Solution manifest import: FAILURE, ErrorCode: -2147188685
Microsoft.Crm.CrmException: Cannot upgrade a patch.
ErrorNumber: 0x80048033
```

But there is nothing more. No more specific detail what is wrong. I also checked ImportJob entity, but there is also nothing specific.

Any ideas what can be wrong or how to fix it?

Comment: Did you check in solution history?

Comment: @ArunVinoth yes, nothing.

Comment: You cannot upgrade a patch, but you can upgrade the solution the patch was applied to.

Comment: @HenkvanBoeijen this is error what is in the trace log

Comment: @BananaCake: to me it seems the process that has created the log tried to upgrade a solution patch instead of the actual solution.